# MySQL query fetch incorrect data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which must fetch payment graphs which must be payed 1 month ago. For example, it must get rows with payment date with 2017.12.04 (post date) and earlier, but it also get data for December 17, 10, etc. this is a query

```
select CONTRACT_ID
from PaymentGraph
where date(now()) >= date_sub(PAYMENT_DATE, interval DAY(LAST_DAY(now())) day)
  and state = 'A'
  and ifnull(paid, 0) < amount
```

I don't know why it works this way, can anybody say what may be the problem?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your date comparison is a bit to complicated, you can write it a bit easier try this:

```
SELECT CONTRACT_ID
FROM PaymentGraph
WHERE PAYMENT_DATE <= curdate() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    AND STATE = 'A'
    AND ifnull(paid, 0) < amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select CONTRACT_ID
from PaymentGraph
where PAYMENT_DATE <= DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
      and state = 'A'
      and (paid < amount or paid is null)
```

This solution is good in a sense that all attributes are SARGable, therefore, an index such as `PaymentGraph(PAYMENT_DATE, state, paid)` can be fully used